# Starting a socket listener/server fundamentals

Tags: python, sockets, http, networking

I was wondering if the following implements all that's needed to have a http server ready to accept localhost connections:

```
import socket

# 1. Create a TCP Socket
listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 

# 2. Bind to a port on localhost
listen_socket.bind(('', 8888))

# 3. Mark it a passive socket so it can "listen" to receive incoming connections
listen_socket.listen(1)

# Receive the connection
while True:
    # do_something()
```

Is this the entire conceptual framework that's needed, or are there other things that I need to do to set up a server? Additionally, I have seen the following command used after creating a socket:

```
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
```

What is the use of doing this and setting this option?

Comment: SO_REUSEADDR helps in situations where you are exiting and restarting the process frequently, e.g. when debugging, as it helps you to avoid 'address already in use' errors on `bind()`.

Comment: @user207421 thank you! I was getting that error every time I tried restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you have set up a socket that can listen to incoming connections, yes. However, you haven't created one that can respond to HTTP requests.

HTTP requests have specific structures to them, for example HTTP requests have a header like as follows:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
```

This parses into the method of the request (GET), the resource requested (index.html stored on the root directory of the server) and the HTTP protocol version (HTTP/1.1). Along with this there are header attributes that you would need to look at to properly interpret any data that is included in the request and to format your response.

It would be useful to read up on the HTTP specification to find out more on the various verbs and commands that you would need to look out for. But this is definitely a step in the right direction!

Comment: right, I'm aware about the client. I can just do `telnet localhost 8888 HTTP/1.1 200 OK` and that works. I'm more concerned about the server. Also what about the `setsockopt` ?